# multiple items being inserted as one item into db

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to accept multiple items from a form and when they reach php for processing, split the items and treat them as seperate items to insert into db. What is happening at the moment, is that the items are being inserted into the db as one item. For example, I enter item1,item2,item3. This is being inserted into the db in one column. all three items in one column. How can I correct my code to have each item in there own column. Many thanks

php page

```
foreach($_POST['BRVbrtrv_boxnumber'] as $i=>$value){
$_POST['BRVbrtrv_boxnumber'][$i]=mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

$boxnumber = implode( ',', $_POST['BRVbrtrv_boxnumber']);

$query = 'INSERT INTO `act` (`service`, `activity`, `department`, `company`,  `address`, `user`, `item`, `destroydate`, `date`, `new`)
         VALUES (\''.$service.'\', \''.$activity.'\', \''.$department.'\', \''.$company.'\', \''.$address.'\', \''.$authorised.'\', \''.strtoupper($boxnumber).'\', NULL, NOW(), \''.$new.'\');';
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
```

jquery input

```
for(var i = 0;i < $(this).val();i++) {
$("#BRVbrtrv_boxnumber").append('<div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="BRVbrtrv_boxnumber" class="ui-input-text">Enter box ' + (i + 1) + ' number:</label><input type="text" name="BRVbrtrv_boxnumber['+i+']" id="BRVbrtrv_boxnumber['+i+']" class="BRV_boxnumber ui-input-text ui-body-null ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-body-c" /></div>')
}
```

json output

```
boxnumber: "rff,tgg" <- this is correct values for 2 items that I input
```

+++UPDATE+++

```
    foreach($_POST['BRVbrtrv_boxnumber'] as $i=>$value){
            $_POST['BRVbrtrv_boxnumber'][$i]= strtoupper( mysql_real_escape_string($value) );
    }

    foreach( $_POST['BRVbrtrv_boxnumber'] as $k => $item_name ){

    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . "GMT" );
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
    header("Pragma: no-cache" );
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    $json = "";
    if(empty($service)) {
    $json .= "{\"ErrorService\": \"ERROR: You mest select a service level\"}";
     }

    else
    if($department=="Choose Department") {
    $json .= "{\"ErrorService\": \"ERROR: You must select a department\"}";
     }

    else
    if($address=="Choose Address") {
    $json .= "{\"ErrorService\": \"ERROR: You must select a retrieval address\"}";
     }

    else
    if(empty($item_name)) {
    $json .= "{\"ErrorService\": \"ERROR: You must enter a box for retrieval\"}";
     }

    else
    {
    $json .= "{\n";
    $json .= "\"boxnumber\": \"".$item_name."\",\n";
    $json .= "\"boxcount\": \"".$boxcount."\"\n";
    $json .= "}\n";
    }
 }
```

Comment: What does your $_POST array look like before the foreach ?

Comment: @interstellar this is the json out put doing just $boxnumber = $_POST['BRVbrtrv_boxnumber'];   {
"boxnumber": "Array",
"boxcount": "2"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST['BRVbrtrv_boxnumber'] as $i=>$value){
        $_POST['BRVbrtrv_boxnumber'][$i]= strtoupper( mysql_real_escape_string($value) );
}

foreach( $_POST['BRVbrtrv_boxnumber'] as $k => $item_name )
{

    $query = 'INSERT INTO `act` (`service`, `activity`, `department`, `company`,  
                                 `address`,  `user`, `item`, `destroydate`, `date`
                                 ,`new`)
   VALUES (\''.$service.'\', \''.$activity.'\', \''.$department.'\', \''.$company.'\',  \''.$address.'\', \''.$authorised.'\', \''.$item_name.'\', NULL, NOW(), \''.$new.'\');';
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
}
```

Comment: I have updated my original code and taken the db out of the equation. I am only returning first box out of 2 input. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the $_POST['BRVbrtrv_boxnumber'], and then have a for loop processing the returned array, in which you do your insert.